# iPhone SDK: Keep an image from scrolling with a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I've been searching all over for an easy way to do this. Right now I have a UIScrollView setup as my main view. There's an Image on the left and a column of TextFields on the right. When any TextField is tapped, the keyboard comes up and hides the bottom TextField. So I have the ScrollView move up to unhide the bottom TextField.

Question #1:
Is there a way to have it respond to a specific TextField instead of all of them?

Question #2:
Is there a way to keep the Image on the left static so it doesn't move with the TextFields?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Question #1:

You can use the UITextFieldDelegate method `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` to see if the last text field was the one that is being used.  Then you can animate the scroll view upwards.

Question #2:

You have a couple options here.  You could make the main view a `UIView`.  Then add the `UIScrollView` as a subview and then add the `UIImageView` as another subview on top of the UIScrollView.  Then when you move the scroll view, the image will stay in the same place.  Another option is to use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method of `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` to animate the image downwards as the scroll view animates upwards or something similar.